# How to highlight the cells containing a specific string in the dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is the dataframe, what I want is to make the null cells 'grey' background color and 'yellow' background color contains the string 'BLANK'. AND only make actions on COLUMN 'B','C','D','E'.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'B' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'QAHQ052', np.nan,'NO AWD'],
                   'C' : [np.nan, '298561806', np.nan,'(BLANK)', np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'D' : [np.nan, np.nan, '26748',np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'E' : ['WER', np.nan, np.nan,'QAC9536, QCD03532, QA39535, (BLANK)', np.nan, 'OGA']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) :

```
def highligth_nan(ser):
    highlight = 'background-color: gray'
    default = ''
    return [highlight if pd.isna(e) else default for e in ser]  

def highligth_blank(ser):
    highlight = 'background-color: yellow'
    default = ''
    return [highlight if 'BLANK' in str(e) else default for e in ser] 

cols = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

(
    df1
     .style
     .apply(highligth_nan, axis=0, subset=cols)
     .apply(highligth_blank, axis=0, subset=cols)
)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Comment: what is color_cells?